# A better way of visualizing extreme oscillation curve in matlibplot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Here are three curve

[image]

All the curve contains so many spikes and noises. I'm interesting to see which curve has less chaos

One way is to use `np.convolve` to smooth the curve. Unfortunately, it lost so much information and defeat my original purposes.

I'm wondering if there different way of visualization ? (Not necessarily plotting the curve but use some math theorem to visualize the chaos in a different way)

Comment: autocorrelation, Fourier analysis

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Flatten out your plot by specifying the width, height for you plot.